# Error GIMBAL iOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon, gimbal

I use the Gimbal SDK. 
When I try to create QLContextCoreConnector on my view compare this message:

[name of my app]
Powered by Gimbal Place detection

[checkbox] I accept the gimbal terms of [...]

I accept and always is ok. But after the loading, on the screen compare this message:

Sorry, Network error. Please try again later.

and in the XCode log screen this is the message that the framework run

```
2014-09-18 12:48:06.837 GimbalDefTest[1102:60b] Failed to initialize gimbal Error Domain=QLRestTemplateErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x1780f7300 {NSUnderlyingError=0x178049630 "The request timed out.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://ios.api.gimbal.com/service/rest/v4/user/43021051/application, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://ios.api.gimbal.com/service/rest/v4/user/43021051/application, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
```

Someone can help me?

ps: I already check the field PRODUCTION_API_KEY in the UserContext.plist with my Gimbal API Key and they matched

Answer (score 1):

The error was in the bundle id. If you want to develop an app with gimbal framework you must to set the same bundle id in the app and in the gimbal manger.